# Are "bots" that only observe the screen allowed?

Tags: runescape

I recently had the idea to create a "bot" or script that would pay attention to a part of the screen and alert me whenever the part of the screen changed according to the parameters I set (and doing nothing else). Would a bot/script like this break the Runescape Terms of Service?

From how I interpreted the rules, it seemed that as long as you were not tracking data you could not obtain normally and not using auto clicking, you were fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Alt1 toolkit](https://runeapps.org/alt1) works exactly like this - it attaches to your Runescape process and observes images. One of the functions is to alert the user before they are lobbied due to the AFK timer.

And it has been approved by an official Jagex staff [over 5 years ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/runescape/comments/3ootg2/alt1_toolkit_guide/cw0ijyk/), stating that since it does not interact with the game directly, it is fine to use. His exact words are:

> "It doesn't appear you can use it to control or automate game play, so it's unlikely it could cause any problems with our anti-cheating detection methods, ie; players shouldn't be banned for using it.
>
> However, with using any 3rd party software, you do so at your own risk, and we'd never condone the use of such software whilst playing RuneScape."
>
> So the TL;DR - it's fine to use, but as with all third party software you need to be careful, and make sure it isn't breaking any of our Rules.

Thus, since your program does not even attach itself to the runescape process, I would say that it is just as safe to use since it does not break Runescape's Terms of Service.

Answer (score 6):

I would say no it is not forbidden.

If it really just takes a screenshot and compares an area of the screenshot with a base image it should not even be traceable by Runescape. Taking a Screenshot is usually nothing they should be able to ban you for. 
Since you say it would only notify you, you still have to put the work into the game yourself.

But obviously botting and scripting is against games term and so you would be better off asking in the Runescape forum or asking a mod about it.

I would not risk my account before I found an answer in the official game forum.

Comment: I don't know where an screenshot compare script would be useful tho, at least not if it's supposed to be a simple one.

Comment: I would agree with this. If it was a script that just took screenshots and compared them then it would probably be OK. But any script that uses the games code to make determinations, even if it is just to compare one part of the screen over and over, I would say that would be against the rules. Even though its not playing the game for you, it still is giving you an advantage which would break the games rules IMO.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I am wondering about it. The bot/script's goal would be that it observes the top part of the screen where the XP circle appears, and when it does not see the XP circle for a set amount of time, it notifies me (for the sake of Fury Shark Outfit Menaphos Fishing). I will probably bring this question to the RS3 Forums or contact a Mod about it.

Comment: "should not even be traceable by Runescape" is kinda wrong here. Runescape can absolutely trace it, since they require administrator rights to run the game. And having admin rights allows them to install anti-cheat at a kernel level which would make this possible. Not saying that they even do it - just that it is very possible.

Answer (score 0):

If Jagex detect any botting software they'll most likely ban you, it doesn't matter if you were doing anything malicious they'll only see that you were using a bot.

Comment: While this is true, I don't believe Jagex can detect software that doesn't directly cause effects in game (such as auto-clickers). Screen capture software exists and there is legitimate use to record/stream gameplay yet people who do both are not banned because of it.